# Find the available number of copies

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the available number of book copies at each branch from book title given as the user input.So far i have tried this:

```
   select (bc.no_of_copies-count(bl.book_id)) as avail 
     from book_copies bc
        , book_loans bl
        , book b
        , book_authors ba 
    where bc.book_id=bl.book_id 
      and bc.branch_id=bl.branch_id 
      and ba.book_id=bc.book_id 
      and b.book_id=ba.book_id 
      and b.book_id=bc.book_id 
      and b.title LIKE '%funda%' 
      and bl.date_in IS NULL 
    GROUP BY bc.branch_id;
```

But it always returns an empty set.
This is the schema that i am using:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK (
    Book_id varchar(100),
    Title   varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (Book_id)
);

CREATE TABLE BOOK_AUTHORS(
    Book_id     varchar(100),
    Authors varchar(100),
    Fname varchar(100),
    Minit varchar(100),
    Lname varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (Book_id, Authors),
    FOREIGN KEY (Book_id) REFERENCES BOOK(Book_id)
);

CREATE TABLE LIBRARY_BRANCH(
    Branch_id   int(5),
    Branch_name varchar(100),
    Address     varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (Branch_id)
);

CREATE TABLE BOOK_COPIES (
    Book_id     varchar(100),
    Branch_id   int(5),
    No_of_copies int(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (Book_id, Branch_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Book_id) REFERENCES BOOK(Book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Branch_id) REFERENCES LIBRARY_BRANCH(Branch_id)
);

CREATE TABLE BORROWER (
    Card_no varchar(100),
    Fname   varchar(100),
    Lname   varchar(100),
    Address varchar(100),
    Phone   varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (Card_no)
);
CREATE TABLE Book_Loans(
    Loan_id varchar(100),

    Book_id     varchar(100),

    Branch_id   int(5),

    Card_no     varchar(100),

    Date_out    date,

    Due_date    date,

    PRIMARY KEY (Loan_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (Book_id) REFERENCES BOOK(Book_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (Branch_id) REFERENCES LIBRARY_BRANCH(Branch_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (Card_no) REFERENCES BORROWER(Card_no)
);
```

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Use proper JOIN syntax.

Comment: What @Mihai means is that you should pretty much always use explicit joins and place the join conditions using ON rather than leaving it to the where clause. All sort of thing will be much more clear if you refactor to that first.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are wanting is:

```
Select Sum(bc.No_of_copies), bc.Branch_id  from BOOK_COPIES bc
INNER JOIN BOOK bk  ON bk.Book_id = bc.Book_id
WHERE bk.Title LIKE '%funda%'
GROUP BY bc.Branch_id
```

Add in whatever other parameters you need (you have date_in but that is not in your tables anywhere, I'm guessing you mean Due_Date, but this framework should get you started).

My thoughts are you will have trouble tracking unique items with this schema.  You have quantities of a particular title, but no way of differentiating a unique item.  You should probably have an instance of each book with a unique id (so if you have 5 copies of Catcher in the Rye, you have 5 IDs for Catcher in the Rye, so you know copy 1 is checked out to Bob, and copy 2 is checked out to Sally, not that Bob has a book and Sally has a book, because what happens when a book gets dropped in the return, is it Bob's or Sally's?)